# Is it that the psychologist comprehends the patient’s behavior or the patient his own behavior

Tags: meaning

https://youtu.be/H5Uq6HvUf2A

> hypnosis does not permit us to recognize the resistance with which the patient clings to his disease and thus even fights against his own recovery; yet it is this phenomenon of resistance which alone makes it possible to comprehend his behavior in daily life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence does not specify who is able to comprehend the behaviour of the patient.

It merely states that *the phenomenon of resistance makes it possible to comprehend....*

It would be possible to insert a number of agents in the sentence, such as:

**...makes it possible for him/us/one/doctors/analysts/the psychologist to comprehend...**

The point that the statement is making is that under certain circumstances, the patient's behaviour is comprehensible, whether by the psychologist, the patient or a third party. Without more context, one doesn't know whether the author has someone specific in mind.